# Setting a variable while reading command line arguments in batch

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a script to open folders that our devs commonly access all the time at work both through the command line and through explorer. Right now this is what it looks like:

```
@echo off

if "%~1" == "" goto noargs
if "%~1" == "/h" goto noargs
if "%~1" == "common1" goto setcommon1
if "%~1" == "common2" goto setcommon2
REM other folders here...

if "%~2" == "-t" (
    set OPENINCMD=1
) else (
    set OPENINCMD=0
)

REM This is where noargs is but I removed it for brevity

:setcommon1
set FOLDERPATH="C:\Users\username\common folder 1"
goto execute
:setcommon2
set FOLDERPATH="C:\Users\username\CommonFolder2"
goto execute

:execute
if %OPENINCMD% EQU 1  (
    cd %FOLDERPATH%
) ELSE (
    explorer.exe %FOLDERPATH%
)
```

But I would like to be able to set the `%FOLDERPATH%` variable as I'm parsing through the command line arguments at the start.

I have tried using `setlocal enableextentsions enabledelayedexpansion` and using `!FOLDERPATH!` instead of `%FOLDERPATH%` while executing and also in place of `FOLDERPATH` while setting the variable. I have also tried using `!FOLDERPATH!` in both places with no luck. I have `endlocal` at the end of my file as well.

This is what I envision it looking like but this doesn't set the `FOLDERPATH` variable when run.

```
...
if "%~1" == "" goto noargs
if "%~1" == "/h" goto noargs
if "%~1" == "common1" set FOLDERPATH="C:\Users\username\common folder 1"
if "%~1" == "common2" set FOLDERPATH="C:\Users\username\CommonFolder2"
...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

At least two mistakes at first sight:

- quoting in `set`
- not defined `OPENINCMD` at the `:execute` point

This could work:

```
rem ... your code here 
rem goto :anypoint
goto :eof

:setOPEN
if "%~2" == "-t" (
    set OPENINCMD=1
) else (
    set OPENINCMD=0
)
goto :eof

REM This is where noargs is but I removed it for brevity

:setcommon1
set "FOLDERPATH=C:\Users\username\common folder 1"
goto execute
:setcommon2
set "FOLDERPATH=C:\Users\username\CommonFolder2"
goto execute

:execute
call :setOPEN
if %OPENINCMD% EQU 1  (
    cd "%FOLDERPATH%"
) ELSE (
    explorer.exe "%FOLDERPATH%"
)
```